# Plotly choropleth map opacity

Tags: r, colors, plotly, choropleth

I'm following the model for building a choropleth map given on this page: https://plot.ly/r/county-level-choropleth/. The polygon colors are somewhat transparent, and nothing I've tried to change the opacity has had any effect.

```
library(ggplot2) # For the demo map data
library(plotly)

ohio_counties <- map_data('county', 'ohio')
# This id simulates the categorical variable I'm trying to represent with color
ohio_counties$id <- letters[ohio_counties$group %% 6 + 1]

ohio_counties %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~long,
          y = ~lat,
          color = ~id) %>%
  add_polygons(line = list(width = 0.4))
```

I've tried adding `opacity = 1` as a parameter to the `plot_ly()` call and in  `add_polygons`, and I've tried using my own custom color scales, but all appear to have the same amount of transparency. I can get rid of the grid lines, but then I'm still stuck with faded pastel colors.

[image]

EDIT: Compare a map made in Plotly versus another I made in Leaflet using the exact same palette, just to the show the difference between what I am getting and what I would like. (Ignore the background leaflet map and county lines, has no effect on the colors.)

### Plotly

[image: Map made in plotly]

### Leaflet

[image: Map made in leaflet]

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your opacity is already maxed out for the default color palette... As you see, I can make the image even less opaque:

```
> ohio_counties %>%
+     group_by(group) %>%
+     plot_ly(x = ~long,
+             y = ~lat,
+             color = ~id,opacity=.2) %>%
+     add_polygons(line = list(width = 0.4))
```

[image: Extremely See-Through]

So, if you use a different color palette (in this case I use viridis::magma)

```
> require(viridis)
> ohio_counties %>%
+     group_by(group) %>%
+     plot_ly(x = ~long,
+             y = ~lat,
+             color = ~id,colors=viridis::magma(6)) %>%
+     add_polygons(line = list(width = 0.4))
```

[image]

Comment: Hm well that's a bummer - I'm already using a custom color palette that in other contexts is much more saturated looking. One would think `opacity = 1` would actually be opaque.

Comment: @BrianStamper Agreed. I suspect that someone with more javascript/css experience than my own might be able to address this on a deeper level, but that isn't my area of expertise... perhaps if you block the lat/long lines underneath the state, it will bother you less?

Comment: In the actual work those lines are removed, I just left that out of my example to keep things minimal. The resulting faded colors are a departure from the specification for the site, which is no good. I've added more example images to show the difference. I can find workarounds, but this really should be something the user can control.

Answer (score 2):

This drove me to distraction. As much as Plotly is getting very powerful, it still has some very basic shortcomings. I was trying to make a choropleth map of Chinese provinces with imported polygon data, but couldn't figure out why the colours were washed out. I also had the problem that adding another trace on top to get black contours would colour the whole map light grey, covering up the colours underneath.

After spending more time than I ought have to figure it out, I finally discovered this in the manual, under scattergeo (because the type of this map is actually not choropleth):

> fillcolor (color)
>
> Sets the fill color. Defaults to a half-transparent
> variant of the line color, marker color, or marker line color,
> whichever is available.

In other words: `color` and `colors` actually work on the line color, not `fillcolor`. When `fillcolor` is not set, it acquires the same color as the line, at 50% opacity. There should be a way for `color` and `colors` to work directly on `fillcolor`, but it appears that's not the case. Fillcolor can only be set to a single colour, not to change its value depending on a variable.

I'm not an expert on Plotly, but this is my understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `alpha=1` in your plot_ly call:

```
ohio_counties %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~long,
          y = ~lat,
          color = ~id,
alpha=1) %>%
  add_polygons(line = list(width = 0.4))
```